# Hartl Rails Tutorial 3rd Edition - Error with password resets Chapter 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently working on the password reset section in Chapter 10 of Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial, 3rd Edition.

When I attempt to reset my password, I get the following error:

```
Started POST "/password_resets" for ::1 at 2015-01-02 12:04:11 -0500
Processing by PasswordResetsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3IzFDLnzyWl56oXiSIDgjemDC+14Hypdn2j5pUHEJVaFVFjpPVh1sxIbA7cr3CDKrMlffDw3QEwN2hI6rvmRwQ==", "password_reset"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Submit"}
Completed 500  in 9ms

ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (1 for 0):
```

In my view, it is telling me that line 8 of the following code is the issue:

```
  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
    if @user
      @user.create_reset_digest
      @user.send_password_reset_email
      flash[:info] = "Email sent with password reset instructions"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Email address not found"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Which is the following line:

```
@user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
```

I've gone over the code multiple times and simply cannot figure this one out...I'm stumped.  Any help would be appreciated/

Comment: What's your exact backtrace?

Comment: So what's about this backtrace? This problem seems unsolvable without this information.

Comment: My apologies, I just restarted the server to post the backtrace and now it is behaving differently.  For some reason it doesn't recognize the login I've been using during development, but it does allow newly registered users to reset their password.  I will repost the question when I figure out what exactly is going on.  Thank you.